# Limit exceed when passing parameters to PutWorkflowRunProperties

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-glue

I am trying to create a push down predicate by using the result from query. Query returns more than 65535 characters. When this parameter is passed to PutWorkflowRunProperties,the glue job throws an error: PutWorkflowRunProperties limit exceeded. Below is a sample output of the query: ( brand= x and client=u and year=2033 and month=12) or ( brand= x and client=u and year=2033 and month=12) or ( brand= x and client=u and year=2033 and month=12). Is there any workout to pass this as a parameter in glue job?